# Heatmap in webgl - using alpha channel for intensity

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, heatmap

I'm trying to develop Heat Map.

My data are many points.

I'm creating a texture and drawing to it all the points, each one with an alpha of `1 / objectsCount`. so the end result with blending will be less transparent places are more heated.

Than, for customing the colors, i'm drawing the texture on the screen and in the fragment shader i'm checking the value of the alpha and changing accordingly.

When i'm drawing 100 objects it is working good. when 1000, not at all. I saw that when the opacity i send as a uniform is less then 0.003 it considered as 0. Might be because of precision. I've put highp wherever I though but i don't manage to find the correct place.

If my algorithm is not correct, i would be glad to hear new one. Tried to figure out how [They did it](http://codeflow.org/entries/2013/feb/04/high-performance-js-heatmaps/) but it far more complicated.

**Drawing to texture shader**

*Vertex Shader*

```
...

uniform float pointSize;
 
void main() {
   gl_Position = LIGHTGLgl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * LIGHTGLgl_Vertex;
   gl_PointSize = pointSize;
}
```

*Fragment Shader*

```
...
uniform highp float opacity;
uniform highp vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D sampler;
void main() {
   highp vec4 usedColor = color;
   gl_FragColor = usedColor * texture2D(sampler, gl_PointCoord );
   gl_FragColor.a *= opacity;
}
```

**Drawing the result on the screen - Shader**

my vertices of the result texture is for drawing on the screen is in clip space this is why i'm not multiplying with the matrices

*Vertex Shader*

```
...
attribute vec2 texCoords;
varying vec2 tex;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = LIGHTGLgl_Vertex;
   tex = texCoords;
}
```

*Fragment Shader*

```
...
uniform sampler2D sampler;
varying vec2 tex;
uniform float objCount;
void main()
{
   highp vec4 f = texture2D(sampler, tex);

   if (f.a > 0.)
   {
      f = vec4(1,0,0,1); // for the test we make it red
   }
   gl_FragColor = f;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head on the keyboard, finally found the solution for my problem.

When creating texture in GL we specify the data type we want to save for each value - r/g/b/a.
We can send there `FLOAT` and we get more precised data for each value.

My problem was that this type was unsigned byte.

In addition, if we want to draw this texture we must specify a webgl extension `OES_texture_float` and maybe also `OES_texture_float_linear` if we use linear filter.

```
// Creating the texture with FLOAT values
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);

// Loading the extensions
gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear');
```

Comment: I'm looking for a webgl heatmap in javascript. The one I'm currently using doesn't any flexible alpha options and I need greater control over it. Did you ever roll this into a reusable library?

Comment: Sorry no.. Our infrastructure is a company code and cannot/not allowed sharing it. But I would help you if you need some guidance